# SharePoint MOSS BDC for reading in opml feeds

Tags: sharepoint, bdc, opml

We currently have some c# code that runs and imports data from a number of opml feeds and stores it in several sql server tables.

We are working in a moss environment and I am thinking the Business Data Catalog may be able to be utilised to make this process more robust/efficient.

Can anyone suggest if it can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can, since the BDC is there spcifically to be able to use external data within sharepoint. You will need to have a SharePoint Enterprise edition license to user the BDC though...

Comment: We have full enterprise moss. Am I right in thinking that the bdc will get the data on the fly, it wont bring any data to moss? Would we still make use of opml feeds? thx

Comment: the querying against the bdc will on the fly yes, the application definition file will describe only how to connect and use the bdc metadata. more info here :http://www.microsoft.com/industry/professionalservices/businessvalue/marshalingarticle.mspx

Comment: Would we still make use of opml feeds or would we be mapping directly to the database?

Comment: to the database is easiest i would say.